# How do you hide a value after you call it through table PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hey i want to hide a value that i am calling.. Its an ID value which is .$row["item_id"].. How can i achieve this?

```
$query = "SELECT * from itemtbl where username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {

        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["item_name"]. "</td><td>" . $row["description"] . "</td><td>"
        . $row["item_pic"]. "</td><td>" . $row["item_id"]. "</td><td>";

        echo '<a href="studentinventoryedit.php?item_name='.$row['item_name'].'"><button title="edit" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil white"></span></button></a>';
        echo '<a href="studentinventoryedit.php"><button title="delete"type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sr"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash white"></span></button></a>';
    }


} else { 
    echo  "</table>"; 
    echo  '<p class="a1"><b>You have no item. Please insert item</p>'; 
}
```

Comment: Don't print it in the `<td>`?

Comment: i need to print it in <td> so that i can pass the value to edit.php

Comment: It looks like a common case of you writing code without actually understanding what it does.  A `<td>` has nothing to do with passing values.  `<td>` is a table column, any plain text placed in it will show up in that column.   The only relevant code here that controls what is passed to your studentinventoryedit.php is the query string: `?item_name=...`

Comment: yeah ?item_name is dummy example.. i want to pass item_id because its unique item_name is not.

Comment: So.. that's where you would pass it.  A query string is the proper way to pass data on links/GET requests.  I recommend you do some more research on the HTML tags you're using and query strings in general.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of putting the value in td, you can assign it to a hidden element or tr row id attribute.

```
 <td><input type='hidden' value='" . $row["item_id"]. "' /></td>
```

Also, close the echo with tr instead of td

Comment: hey i tried using it.. it works as i can pass the value to another form.. but i have 1 more problem which is that it generates a new  row but with no value.. i dont want to show the 0 row.. how do i do that?

Comment: `if(!empty($row["item_id"])){
 // Your code here
 }

`

Comment: its not working.. it still shows the 0 rows

Comment: @Sonal, I don't see the relevance of this code.  The OP doesn't appear to be using a form and you haven't even assigned a name to this input.  This code won't accomplish anything for the OP, much like having item id in a <td>.

Comment: I am using a form method=GET.. its just that i didn't show the full code of mine

Comment: @Devon If you didn't understand the question, then ask for clarification. Rather pushing your own logic.

Comment: Ahh i see now i just delete the front <td> before the input type='hidden' now the code works and it doesn't show 0 row values.. Thank you @Sonal Borkar

Comment: Welcome @KingJ! Happy Coding